# use FileInputStream and FileOutputStream as a buffer

Tags: java, buffer, fileinputstream, fileoutputstream

I would like to use the hard drive as a buffer for audio signals. My Idea was to just write the samples in byte form to a file, and read the same with another thread. However, I have to problem that `FIS.read(byte[]);` returns 0 and gives me an empty buffer.

What is the problem here?

This is my operation for writing bytes:

```java
try {       
        bufferOS.write(audioChunk);
        bufferOS.flush();
} catch (IOException ex) {
       //...
}
```

And this is what my reader does:

```java
byte audioChunk[] = new byte[bufferSize];
int readBufferSize;
int freeBufferSize =  line.available(); // line = audioline, available returns free space in buffer

try {            
    readBufferSize = bufferIS.read(audioChunk,freeBufferSize, 0);

} catch(IOException e) {
     //...
}
```

I create both `bufferOS` and `bufferIS` with the same file, both work.
The writer works, the file gets created and has the correct data in it.
However the `bufferIS.read();`-call always returns `0`.
The `fileInputStream` returns the correct amount of available bytes with `buffer.available();` and parameters like `freeBufferSize` and `audioChunk.length` are correct.

Is there a problem with running `FileInputStream` and `FileOutputStream` on the same file in windows?

Comment: The reader and the writer are in the same JVM process?

Comment: Its one application but different threads. (The reader becomes its own thread, the writer is executed by the main thread)

Comment: Ok, and how does the writer notify the reader? And how does the reader get instructed with the offset and length of the data in the file?

Comment: They run independent from each other. The writer writes audio-bytes in the file when ever he gets new ones. The reader reads how many he needs in a loop with some milliseconds in between. If there are not enough bytes, he just reads as many as there are. 

This is aqually a data queue with the problem that old bytes are not  discarded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're passing the arguments in the wrong order to the `read` call, it should be:

```
readBufferSize = bufferIS.read(audioChunk, 0, freeBufferSize);
```

Right now you're passing `freeBufferSize` as the offset to store the result of the `read` call and `0` as the number of bytes to read at maximum. It's not surprising that, if you tell the `read` call to read at most zero bytes, that it returns that it has read zero bytes.

Javadoc:

> ```
>  * @param      b     the buffer into which the data is read.
>  * @param      off   the start offset in array <code>b</code>
>  *                   at which the data is written.
>  * @param      len   the maximum number of bytes to read.
>  * @return     the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or
>  *             <code>-1</code> if there is no more data because the end of
>  *             the stream has been reached.
> ```

```
public abstract class InputStream implements Closeable {
    // ....
    public int read(byte b[], int off, int len) throws IOException
```